# how to change sql queries to yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to change the following `sql` query to `yii2`.

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.name_of_flight, a.time_of_flight, (no_of_passenger-b.cnt) as avail 
FROM 
    flight_schedule a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT flight_time, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM book_eticket WHERE flight_date='2016-06-01' GROUP BY flight_time) b 
ON a.id = b.flight_time
```

Comment: Explain better your question eventually show the rest of your code ... this question is not clear

Comment: USe Joinwith concept

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can use this logic.
For more detail pls visit [official](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#count()-detail) page.

```
flight_schedule::find()
    ->select(['id', 'name_of_flight', ' time_of_flight'])
    ->distinct()
    ->joinWith('bookEticket')
    ->all();
```

And add relation to flight_schedule model:

```
public function getBookEticket()
{
    $this->hasOne(book_eticket::className(), ['id' => 'flight_time']);
}
```